# Find an example that an uniformly bounded sequence on set E need not have a pointwise convergent subsequence on E.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

sin(nx) is one example for this.so what could be another better example with explanation.

Comment: $f_n$ are functions? What is a pointwise subsequence?

Comment: Sry,itz pointwise cgt subsequence